# How to reset docker container to the initial state when first made with pulled image

Tags: docker

I 
I want to reset the container to the initial state - the first state when I start to run the container from the image. So I totally removed the container and built new one with the pulled image. But the problem is when I did as follows, the container is not in the state it should be - remember the state just before removed.

```
1) $ docker stop {container-id}

2) $ docker rm {container-id}

3) $ docker pull {image_url}

4) $ docker run {image id from 3)}

5) $ docker start {container id from 4)}
```

It seems that I missed some steps while doing above. 
I suspect that some features of the previous container, like volumes, are not totally removed. But I don't know what really they are or how to remove them.
Is there anything that comes to your mind?
(The state of image is guaranteed to be fine.)

Comment: do `docker volume rm volume_name` after a container is removed. Or if you want to prune every unused volumes, run  `docker volume prune`

Comment: @MjZac thanks! Are there any ways to see the list of volumes related to the container?

Answer (score 0):

`docker start` starts one or more stopped containers, which may still have that state.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/start/

you have to use `docker run IMAGE` if you want a clean state.

Comment: Then, if  I do `docker run IMAGE`, does this make a new container with the new fresh state?